# How to deselect non-manifold geometry?

Tags: python, mesh, selection-tools

We can select non-manifold geometry by python function `select_non_manifold()` or Select Non Manifold command in editor. However, in my case I need to **de**select non-manifold geometry. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Let's have some selection, from which we want to deselect non-manifold geometry:

   [image]
2. Invert selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>:

   [image]
3. Select non-manifold <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>:

   [image]
4. Invert selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>:

   [image]
5. Tadaa!

Comment: Could you please check the chat on here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59406/room-for-tak-and-jerryno